# Nativescript RadSideDrawer does not show content and app breaks when trying to open the drawer

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-telerik-ui

I have set up the RadSideDrawer as in Telerik documentation. App builds and loads successfully but sidedrawer content is not shown and when trying to swipe the screen to open the sidedrawer application crashes with following error:

```
An uncaught Exception occurred on "main" thread.
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.FrameLayout.setVisibility(int)' on a null object reference
at com.telerik.android.primitives.widget.sidedrawer.RadSideDrawer.handleOnDown(RadSideDrawer.java:460)
at com.telerik.android.primitives.widget.sidedrawer.RadSideDrawer.onGesture(RadSideDrawer.java:438)
at com.telerik.android.primitives.widget.sidedrawer.RadSideDrawer.onInterceptTouchEvent(RadSideDrawer.java:420)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2109)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2554)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2198)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2554)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2198)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2554)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2198)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2554)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2198)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2554)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2198)
at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2403)
at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1737)
at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2843)
at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2364)
at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:9527)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4248)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4101)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3647)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3700)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3666)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3792)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3674)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3849)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3647)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3700)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3666)
```

This is package json file:

```
{
  "description": "NativeScript Application",
  "license": "SEE LICENSE IN <your-license-filename>",
  "readme": "NativeScript Application",
  "repository": "<fill-your-repository-here>",
  "nativescript": {
    "id": "org.nativescript.app",
    "tns-android": {
      "version": "3.1.1"
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~4.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "~4.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~4.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "~4.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~4.1.0",
    "@angular/http": "~4.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~4.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "~4.1.0",
    "moment": "^2.18.1",
    "nativescript-angular": "~3.1.0",
    "nativescript-cardview": "^2.0.2",
    "nativescript-loading-indicator": "^2.3.2",
    "nativescript-telerik-ui": "^3.0.4",
    "nativescript-theme-core": "~1.0.2",
    "reflect-metadata": "~0.1.8",
    "rxjs": "~5.3.0",
    "tns-core-modules": "~3.1.0",
    "underscore": "^1.8.3",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-traverse": "6.25.0",
    "babel-types": "6.25.0",
    "babylon": "6.17.4",
    "lazy": "1.0.11",
    "nativescript-dev-typescript": "~0.5.0",
    "tslib": "^1.7.1",
    "typescript": "~2.2.1"
  }
}
```

I have installed `nativescript-ng2-drawer-seed` and it works correctly. I am missing something but i cannot find out. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: If you can share what your Page XML/HTML and JavaScript/TypeScript is we may be able to find the issue. Maybe you have declared the RadSideDrawer beside another UI element, by design the RadSideDrawer should be the single child element of a Page.

Comment: @VladimirAmiorkov Thanks for your help. It was a simple mistake on my part. I have imported `NativeScriptUISideDrawerModule` in AppModule but not in the module of the pages I use sidedrawer.

Answer (score 1):

Solved the problem. Just import `NativeScriptUISideDrawerModule` in the module of the page you are using the sidedrawer. Or just put it in an Angular Shared Module.